# how to use a number value returned from a funtion for further calculation

Tags: javascript, function, return

am new to functions

consider a function named `price`;

when i call the function it returns a value of number `16`

that is

```
price();
```

will return `16`;

i need to use this 16 to add with another number that comes from another function...

anybody please help me..how can i do that

```
const price = function() {
  list.forEach((radio) => {
    radio.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (radio.checked) {
        let rate = radio.value;
        // console.log(rate);
        return rate;
      }
    })
  })
}
```

```
 let amnt= +price();
     let selectedSeats=document.querySelectorAll('.row .seat.selected');
     let totalseat=selectedSeats.length;
     let total= amnt*totalseat;
     console.log(total);
```

am getting NAN on console

i need to take the value returning from price();    for further calculation

Comment: The `price()` function doesn't return anything. It creates event listeners, but they don't return until the user clicks on something, and the return value isn't used for anything then.

Comment: Returning a value from an event listener isn't useful, the event listener needs to do something with the `rate` value itself, like display it in a DIV.

Comment: Otherwise you had to use promise with handling of it but this will be for a beginner much to complicated.

Comment: You need to rethink how this code works. If you showed more code we could point in you the right direction.

Comment: ok thanks..then can you please tell me a way to take that rate value out of that code block and use further..actually its a radio input,,,,so i need to use event listne click

Answer (score 1):

As your operations are dependent on click event, you can't perform further operations until click is made.
So wrap your operation inside click listener.

```
const price = function() {
  list.forEach((radio) => {
    radio.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (radio.checked) {
        let rate = radio.value;
        // console.log(rate);
        let selectedSeats=document.querySelectorAll('.row .seat.selected');
        let totalseat=selectedSeats.length;
        let total= rate*totalseat;
        console.log(total);
      }
    })
  })
}
```

If there are any global variables you can assign them values from inside event too.

Comment: This would be correct if `price()` actually returned a number, but his premise is wrong.

Comment: @Barmar if you could check?

Comment: What's the point of defining a separate variable `amnt`? Just use `rate`.